# Optimum base length for wall divider

Tags: plywood, measurement

I've built the wall divider with plywood sheet, 78" (2m) height and 59" (1.5m) width.

Is there any formula for calculating the proper length of the base for maximum stability?

[image]

Comment: There isn't a single length these should be. It's only partly about stability, part of the decision should be aesthetics (how you want it them to look). But if you're not fussy about their length visually then ignore formulas (if there are any) and just do a quick couple of tests with bits of scrap wood to find out directly what minimum length is needed for the stability you feel is necessary. It would be my bet that a length that "looks about right" will be a pretty good compromise between too short and providing good stability.

Comment: Another factor weighing against going "too long", that in my opinion is very worth considering: at what length might the base become a tripping hazard?